# My cake falls while baking

Tags: baking, cake

I have been trying to follow some recipes in the book "The European Cake Cookbook" by Tatyana Nesteruk.

Several recipes have a similar style which is...
beating 6-7 whole eggs with sugar for about 5 minutes until "pale and voluminous".
Then fold in flour and baking powder.

I find that these cakes consistently seem fine when they go into the oven, but they consistently collapse during the baking process.  Collapse as in 1/3 to 1/2 of their height compared to when they entered the oven.

A specific example from a recipe:
6 large eggs (btw, my eggs are 68 grams each)
150 grams sugar
1 tsp vanilla extract
* whisk together on high speed for 4-6 minutes until pale and voluminous

```
Sift these dry ingredients into the egg mixture and gently fold in:
  125 grams all purpose flour
  25 grams almond flour
  1 tsp baking powder

Bake at 177C for 20 minutes
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you use plain flour or self rising?

Comment: When you say they collapse in the baking process do you mean they collapse in the oven during baking, or they collapse after you take them out?

Comment: @Willeke  plain, all purpose flour.   not self-rising.

Comment: @GdD collapse in the oven while baking.  baking time is 20 minutes...  probably about 10-15 minutes in to the 20 minutes, I can see through the glass oven door that it has collapsed down.

Comment: a typical genoise sponge (which uses the egg foam method as you described), based on the amount of sugar and flour in your recipe, would only use (approximately) 2 eggs. your recipe seems to be more like a souffle (it doesn't have much structure).

Comment: @Willeke cakes (genoise, viennese, mousseline, etc) made using the Egg Foam method (as described by the OP) don't use self raising flour. the lift is made by the foaming of the eggs.

Comment: @MrShane, that is why I asked, as some people may not know that and use self rising flour or add a rising agent and it fails because of that.

Comment: I now see they do add a teaspoon of baking powder. Not sure if that is the reason but I might be. (Not that much of a baker myself, just know some of the problems.)

Comment: I was able to contact the author of the cookbook through her website.  Her suggestions basically came down to that maybe my oven runs hot and to try lowering the temperature down 5-10 degrees to see if that helps.